# How to deal with participants who fail comprehension checks non-randomly

Tags: missing-data, survey, bias

Let's say I'm running a study evaluating the effects of time pressure on some decision making task.  I add a comprehension check to ensure participants understand the task they are about to complete, and the comprehension check involves some element of time pressure.   The control condition gets no such comprehension check because their task does not involve time pressure.

Now, let's say 40% of the treatment fails the comprehension check.  I can see two approaches to dealing with this:

1. I remove from the dataset all individuals who fail the comprehension check
2. I include all the observations, regardless of whether or not they pass the comprehension check, and add a dummy variable for passing the comprehension check.

Which of these two approaches is preferable?  Is there a better approach than either of these?

More importantly, it strikes me that both of these approaches suffer from the problem that the comprehension check itself covaries with the treatment (in a somewhat unavoidable way).  Is it possible to find a treatment effect, even after doing option #2, that is somehow "caused" by comprehension check?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:dropout] tag because your question does not appear to be about dropout in the sense used by the tag. You can read the tag wiki for more information.

Comment: To clarify: your control group does not undergo the same process as your treatment group? (Except for the treatment itself.) or is the lack of time pressure your treatment? Also, I wonder if the 40% who don’t comprehend what you intend for them to do are meaningful data points.

Comment: @Wayne, the control group has to make decisions, but are free from time pressure.  The treatment group makes the same decisions as the control group, but with no time pressure.  The "comprehension check" for the treatment group involves making decisions WITH time pressure, whereas the comprehension check for the control group involves no such time pressure.

The comprehension check question will be something like: "Select answer choice C."  And you fail the comprehension check if you don't select "C."

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that the treatment group HAS time pressure above

Comment: So the lack of time pressure _is_ your treatment. And your comprehension check is essentially an order placed among the actual decisions you are asking them to make. Correct?

Comment: @Wayne, the PRESENCE of time pressure is the treatment.  I corrected the typo in the 1st comment.  The comprehension check is a list of decisions similar to the decisions that the treatment group will have to actually do, except one of the questions has answer choices that are simply impossible if the participant actually understands the question.  If the participant has selected one of these "impossible" answer choices, we say they didn't pass the comprehension check / attention check

Comment: Adding time pressure can affect our ability to comprehend even the simplest of instructions. So, I don't see how the "comprehension check" question is any different from other questions in your task except for the fact that it is easier. It certainly doesn't seem reasonable to me to discard individuals based on their response to a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really good [paper on post-treatment variables](http://pages.wustl.edu/montgomery/posttreatmentbias) that mentions:

> If passage rates on an attention check are rejected by the treatment for any
>   reason, then dropping respondents who fail it would be the equivalent of dropping cases on a post-treatment covariate and would again risk bias.

So, yes, your concern is valid. I believe they talk about possible techniques to handle this case.

I'm not an expert, but my gut is that you should: 1) document what percentage of the control group failed the check. 2) Analyze all of the data, ignoring the check question, as if the question weren't asked.

By ignoring the check question, you won't commit post-treatment bias -- which in your case could be severe I think -- but you will add some noise because of participants who were not paying attention.

But you do at least have a baseline percentage of check failure in the control group. Hopefully it's low. I think we could say that a similar proportion of the treatment group would also fail the check if stress were not part of the treatment, so that proportion of the whole would give a rough idea of how much noise -- meaningless surveys -- we introduced into our study by "not doing" (not using, actually) an attention check.

(For the record, your original posting seems to imply that the check is a question about the task ahead, that's administered before the survey. But I think it's a question slipped into the survey to check comprehension/attention.)

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks so much, Wayne.